# Python overwriting variable in script 1 with user input from script2

Tags: python, input, python-2.x

I've been struggling with this for several days now, and I cant find any answers that actually relate to what I'm trying to do, at least none that I can find.

I am trying to create a basic system for keeping track of my finances (i.e. cash, whats in the bank, etc). I have two scripts: display.py and edit.py.
The idea is that I can easily pull up display.py and see how much I have and where it is, and use edit.py to change the amounts shown in display.py, without having to open Vi or entering the numbers every time i run display.py.

In theory, edit.py would take user input, and then overwrite the value in display with that new input, so that display is independent of edit and saves those values

display.py:

```
cash1 = "5.14"
bank1 = "none"

print "you have", cash1, "in your pocket"
print ""
print ""you have", bank1, "in the bank"
```

and using this in edit.py

```
f = open("display.py", "r")
contents = f.readlines()
f.close()
cashinput1 = "cash1"
cashinput2 = raw_input("enter the new coin amount: ")
cashtransfer =  ("=".join((cashinput1,cashinput2,)))
contents.insert(5, cashtransfer)
f = open("display.py", "w")
contents = "".join(contents)
f.write(contents)
f.close()
```

I know edit.py isn't very clean, but the problem is that it's adding the input to the end of a line, pushing it to the next one. The goal is overwrite cash1, not add another. I've tried simply importing, but that doesn't work as the changes aren't saved.

tl;dr How do I overwrite a variable in one script with user input from another script? 
I'm using Python 2.7.12

thanks in advance.

EDIT: Sqlite3 looks designed for this type of thing, so this question is answered. Not sure how to close this without any answers though.

Comment: It's generally a bad idea to store information directly in your scripts, let alone modifying the source file to accomplish any of this. Maybe if you tell us what you're trying to do we can recommend a sane approach. I suspect you should create a simple database or even just a csv file containing your data (not a .py file)

Comment: You could keep the data in a text file and modify it as needed. `edit` modifies this file and `display` displays it

Comment: You should think about just storing it in a file. Then both applications can pull from said file. If you do it as an `ini` file Python has a great built in lib for that.

Comment: Hm, I see your points.  @Suever I suppose the base goal is to edit the file without opening an editor. Was trying to incorporate these into a larger program, so editing it wouldn't require something like Vi or leafpad

Comment: @Nameless477 Use `sqlite3` as mentioned above for a very simple database where you can store your data *especially* if this is going to be part of a larger application

Comment: @Suever that looks like it will work with what I'm trying to do, thanks! and thanks to the rest of you guys too :)

Answer (score 0):

As I've been pointed toward Sqlite3, I will use that. Thanks again, question answered :)